# ssh with only private key on aws ec2 instance giving permission denied public key error

Tags: ssh

I have generated public private key pair using ssh-keygen on server2 and copy the private key from server2 to server1 as priv.pem, changed the permission to 600 and now tried ssh -i priv.pem ec2-user@<ip_of_server_2> from server 1 but I am getting permission denied public key error while trying ssh

Comment: did you copy the one line public key to `authorized_keys` on server2 ?  (along with proper right)

Comment: You might try `ssh -vvv` to turn on verbose debug output and examine this output for more details on the error.  Does /etc/ssh/sshd_config on the server contain `PubkeyAuthentication yes`? Does  the client /etc/ssh/config include `PubkeyAuthentication yes`?

Comment: Ayush, did you enter passphrase (during ssh-keygen)? Maybe now, while you are trying to connect to server2, you are entering wrong passphrase? It would be useful if you put exact error line/s you get or even exact steps with exact commands you used.

Comment: @Archemar I need only private key authentication without adding public key in **authorized_keys** on server2

Comment: you don't have "private key authetification", you store public key in authorized_keys, when ssh connection is established, sshd issue a challenge with public key that only onwer of private key can satisfy. if ssh client have a default private key, sshd --server part -- didn't have default public key.

Comment: @Archemar Issue resolved. Thanks for the clarification

Comment: @ayushpratapsingh, it would be nice to write what the problem was and how it was solved, not just "Problem solved". The community has nothing from "Problem solved".

Comment: @Damir the use was that I was trying to access the server B from server A without public key copying in authorized_key file on server B. So the error is occuring now when I copied pulic key of server A from where I want to access server B, I am able to access now server B from server A